# Remove beep from message dialog

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, python-2.7

I've tried to google it and I've looked in the wxpython docs but I just can't seem to find a way-- can you remove the annoying "error" beep that `wx.MessageDialog` makes when it pops up (aka when you call `.ShowModal()`)?

Comment: I just noticed the beep goes away if you add the style flag `style=wx.ICON_QUESTION`, but that isn't exactly what I was looking for since it also displays a large question mark I don't necessarily want on every message dialog.

Comment: I think that's standard platform behaviour (are you using Windows?)

Comment: Yes I am. I understand that certain styles of MessageDialog boxes are intended to have the sound, I'm just wondering if there's a way through wxpython to supress it without being forced to use the `style=wx.ICON_QUESTION` flag.

Comment: I don't think so, sorry (just done a bit of googling about disabling a MessageBox sound [not wx specific])

Answer (score 3):

You may try switching to [wx.lib.agw.genericmessagedialog](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.genericmessagedialog.html) and see if the problem goes away.